# Start systemd timer from Python

Tags: python, systemd, dbus

I'm trying to start a dbus timer from python.

At the moment I was able to launch it through this script:

```
import dbus
from subprocess import call

def scheduleWall( time, message ):
   call(['systemd-run --on-active='+str(time) +' --unit=scheduled-message --description="'+ message +'" wall "'+ message +'"'], shell=True)
```

I'd like to not use "call", but try to use "StartTransientUnit", but I wasn't able to understand the format of the call at all! I'm rather new to dbus and python.

```
def scheduleWall( time, message ):

  try:
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    systemd1 = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.systemd1"," /org/freedesktop/systemd1")
    manager = dbus.Interface(systemd1, 'org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager')
    obj = manager.StartTransientUnit('scheduled-message.timer','fail',[????],[????])
  except:
    pass
```

Is startTransientUnit the right method to call? how should I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: stick to `systemd-run` :)

I don’t think `StartTransientUnit` is quite the right method – you need to create *two* transient units, after all: the timer unit, and the service unit that it will start (which will run `wall` later). Perhaps you can use `StartTransientUnit` for the timer, but at least not for the service. You also need to set all the properties that the two units need (`OnActiveSec=` for the timer, `ExecStart=` for the service, probably some more…) – you can see how `systemd-run` does it by running `busctl monitor org.freedesktop.systemd1` and then doing `systemctl run --on-active 1s /bin/true` in another terminal. (The main calls seem to be `UnitNew` and `JobNew`.)

I’ll admit, to me this seems rather complicated, and if `systemd-run` already exists to do the job for you, why not use it? The only change I would make is to eliminate the shell part and pass an array of arguments instead of a single space-separated string, with something like this (untested):

```
subprocess.run(['systemd-run', '--on-active', str(time), ' --unit', 'scheduled-message', '--description', message, 'wall', message)
```

Comment: In the end I used subprocess.run. But i'll try to study busctrl command .
Thank you